# placement of an item

Tags: html, css, layout, drop-down-menu

Please have a look at the fiddle I am posting, and tell me how to make the menu icon (the three asteriks (*)) appear next to the welcome user menu. ie, on the same line, and not beneath it.

[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/HarrietFiddles/eggxm74f/30/)

here is a code snippet:

```css
/*DROPDOWN FUNCTIONALITY*/
ul { 
 padding:0; 
 margin:0
}
a {
 display:block;
 text-decoration: none;
}
li {
 display:block; 
 float:left;
}
li ul li {
 float:none;
}
li ul {
 display:none; 
 position:absolute; 
 z-index:1
}
li:hover ul {
 display:block;
}

/*DROPDOWN STYLING:*/
#menu {
 height:30px
}
#menu a {
 color:#024E67; 
 padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;
}
#menu a:hover {
 color:#ffffff;
}
#menu li {
 background-color:#FFF; 
 margin-left:-1px
}
#menu li:hover {
 background-color:#61b4cf
}
i {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
     <div id="UserSettings" name="UserSettings" class="UserSettings">
        <!-- offer welcome message to user logged in -->
        <div class="welcomeText" id="welcomeText" name="welcomeText">
        <label>Welcome SuperUser</label>
          <ul id="menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars" title="Menu"></i>***</a>
              <ul>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog" title="Preferences"></i>Preferences</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user" title="Active Sessions"></i>Active Sessions</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lock" title="Change Password"></i>Change Password</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
```

`

Comment: is it what you are expecting https://jsfiddle.net/eggxm74f/31/?

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: inline-block;` for `ul` **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/eggxm74f/31/)**

```
ul {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```